A place somewhere in Europe

Add another circle, a rectangle and an oval to the circle shown above and turn it into a public place where hundreds of people come and go every day

This is a really good example of a short, simple knowledge puzzle with a clever twist and a satisfying 'aha' moment. I shall use this as an example to others asking for a quick mental runaround for sure. Very nice :)

@Stiv Great puzzle for sure, but out of reach of many not from that area, which is totally fine. Just being objective.

@JLee V zlfrys vf sebz HF. Ohg V qb qvfgvapgyl erzrzore gur Erq Pvepyr naq erpgnatyr bs gur Ybaqba Haqretebhaq. Vg vf bar bs gur zbfg erpbtavmrq ybtbf sbe gbhevfgf nyy bire. Urapr gur vqrn sbe gur chmmyr.

@JLee And that's why it's a knowledge puzzle :) Although if people are into quizzing (which would likely make them the kind of folks a knowledge puzzle is primarily aimed at) this tends to be one of the areas you learn about no matter where you're from, just like how one would cover US state capitals, flags of the world, islands of Japan, and the Seven Summits, for example...

Well this has gotta be...

 

The Oval tube station in London!

